# cgo undefined reference to

Tags: go, cgo

go project structure

```
src
  test.go
  testc/collection/linkedlist.h
  testc/collection/linkedlist.c
```

test.go

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "testc/collection/linkedlist.h"
import "C"

func main() {
  C.insertFirst(1,10);
  C.insertFirst(2,20);
  C.insertFirst(3,30);
  C.insertFirst(4,1);
  C.insertFirst(5,40);
  C.insertFirst(6,56);
  C.printList();
}
```

linkedlist.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef TEST_LINKEDLIST_H
#define TEST_LINKEDLIST_H
struct node {
    int data;
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node * getHeader();
void printList();
void insertFirst(int key, int data);
struct node* deleteFirst();
bool isEmpty();
int length();
struct node* find(int key);
struct node* delete(int key);
void sort();
void reverse(struct node** head_ref);
//void testList();
#endif //TEST_LINKEDLIST_H
```

the error

```
# command-line-arguments
d:/gcc-9.2.0-no-debug/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b001\_x002.o: in function `_cgo_8b2a34aa27ef_Cfunc_insertFirst':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:62: undefined reference to `insertFirst'
d:/gcc-9.2.0-no-debug/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: $WORK\b001\_x002.o: in function `_cgo_8b2a34aa27ef_Cfunc_printList':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:74: undefined reference to `printList'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# command-line-arguments
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_8b2a34aa27ef_Cfunc_printList':
cgo-gcc-prolog:72:49: warning: unused variable '_cgo_a' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: Could you please provide the complete source code for reproduce the error?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Your have to omit the `testc` folder, because they are in the same path in the import.
So this import:

```golang
// #include "testc/collection/linkedlist.h"
```

will be:

```golang
// #include "collection/linkedlist.h"
```